# After upgrading a PS3 hard drive, can I put the old one back in?

Tags: ps3

Let's say I had a 60GB Playstation 3, and I bought a new 500GB hard drive to replace the old one.  I take the 60GB hard drive out of the machine, put the 500GB one in, format it, and get started and..
"Oops! I forgot to back something up from the old hard drive!"

Can I take the 500GB hard drive back out and put the 60GB drive back in (remember, this is the **same** console; not a new one), and will it still recognize the old drive properly so I can perform a backup?

Comment: For those playing along, this is an alternative take on a previous question that was deemed too similar to another question. I haven't seen this specific one asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have no problems, don't worry. Just put it back in and copy the data, like save games and songs, to another pen drive or something and then vice versa.